# If $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} p(z) = \infty$, then $p(z)$ is a constant

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Claim:

> If $p$ is an entire function and $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} p(z) = \infty$ and $p(z) \neq 0$ $\forall z \in \Bbb C$, then $p(z)$ is a constant.

Proof:

Define $f(z) = \frac{1}{p(z)}$ so $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} f(z) = 0$. Then there exists an $N > 0$ such that $\lvert f(z) \rvert \leq 1$ for all $\lvert z \rvert > N$. Take the closed disk $\lvert z \rvert \leq N$. Since this disk is compact and $f$ is continuous, there exists an $M > 0$ such that $\lvert f(z) \rvert \leq M$ for all $\lvert z \rvert \leq N$. Since $f(x)$ is bounded and entire, by Liouville $f(x)$ is a constant so $p(z)$ is a constant.

Since it is obvious that a constant function cannot go to $\infty$, where is the fallacy in this proof since the statement seems not to be true?

Comment: The statement is true because the hypotheses are never satisfied.

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs Oh No.. :D i did not see that properly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no fallacy as the **implication** is true.

The fact that the premise and the conclusion then are in contradiction can be used to conclude that *the only way* the implication can be true is that it is vacuously true, that is *there is no function* that fulfills the premise.

Formally, this is the same as saying, for $x$ a non-zero real:

> If $x^3>0$ and $1/x^2 < 0$, then $x < 0$.

Proof: $x = x^3 (1/x^2)< 0$ as the product of a positive and a negative number is negative.

Of course there is no $x$ such that $x^3>0$ and $x<0$. But, this is no problem as there is no $x$ such that $x^3>0$ and $1/x^2 < 0$ either.

Answer (score 2):

You arrived at a contradiction, so you in fact have a correct proof that if $f$ is entire and nonconstant, then $\lim_{z \to \infty} f(z)$ does not exist in the extended complex plane.

Comment: But there was no claim that the function is non-constant

Comment: No, but if $f$ is entire and constant then (trivially) the limit as $z \to \infty$ exists. Your proof shows that if $f$ is nonconstant the limit cannot exist.